# Tomcat is a web-server or web-container

Tags: java, tomcat

I got little confused by [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Getting_Started_Guide/beta422/html/The_JBoss_Server___A_Quick_Tour-The_Web_Container___Tomcat.html) article whether tomcat is web container or web server.
I have seen in so many places like [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-tomcat-webserver-and-not) that tomcat is a web server

Need an clear explanation here.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is a web server and a servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

A web server serves pages for the user.
Tomcat can do this, but so can other apps more dedicated for this.

Tomcat can contain web applications in their own separate container.
So, tomcat is a web container, and specialised for J2EE web apps.

Does that help?

Comment: There's no such thing as J2EE since 2003

Comment: Its not really specialized either though, it doesn't even provide JSF out of the box which is the main web component of the JEE specification. Its just a servlet container, relating it to JEE is a step too far.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is both Web server and Servlet container.

The term Web server here denotes that Tomcat can serve static contents like html, css, js, images and so on.

Servlet container refers to procession/compiling jsp and servlet and creating a html page.

Tomcat can perform both, but in large scale production environments Tomcat is mostly used only as a Servlet Container and Apache/nginx is used to serve static contents. The reason for this is Apache/nginx are good in serving static contents than that of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a web server but noways it is also know as application server cause it it adds new feature like connection pooling and etc., Tomcat supplies container for **Servlet** and **JSP** as **Catalina** and **Jasper** respectively. so you can say tomcat is both.